# Lyndon Words, why isn't 00, 11 in the sequence.

Tags: combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

Im trying to understand the relationship between lyndon words and necklaces.  The sequence for lyndon words is: $$ ε, 0, 1, 01, 001, 011, 0001, 0011, 0111, 00001, 00011, 00101, 00111, 01011, 01111 $$
For Necklaces the following sequence includes 00, 01, *and* 11:
[image]

Why don't lyndon words contain 00 and 11?  I have read that

> A Lyndon word is an aperiodic notation for representing a necklace.

but clearly the necklace of 00 and 11 is not being represented.  Also why is 0101 not included but 00101 is?

Answer (score 4):

By definition, a Lyndon word is a word that is lexicographically smaller than every of its rotations (where $z$ is a rotation of $z'$ iff there exist words $u,v$ such that $z=uv$ and $z'=vu$.). If a word is a power (i.e., a concatenation of copies of a shorter word), then it cannot be Lyndon. Indeed, in this case there is a rotation that equals the original word, so that the original word is not *strictly smaller* than every of its rotations.

If you relax the condition in the definition by imposing that a word must be *smaller or equal* than every of its rotations, then you get the definition of a necklace. In fact, necklaces are just powers of Lyndon words (meaning that a necklace is a word of the form $u^n$, for a Lyndon word $u$ and an integer $n\geq 0$).

Answer (score 2):

It's because both $00$ and $11$ are periodic, and are covered already by the inclusion of $0$ and $1$.